# uso do distinct em um dropdownlist

Tags: c#, mvc, razor

Estou querendo retirar nomes iguais do meu dropdownlist, mas são de id's diferentes.
Queria aonde teria que implantar o codigo se seria na view, ou no controller em algum outro lugar.

Dados na tabela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E esse é como fica o dropdownlist[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é minha view:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.NomeProdutoId)
@Html.LabelFor(a => a.NomeProdutoId, "Escolher Produto:")
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.NomeProdutoId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Compra, "Id", "NomeProduto"))
```

Essa e a linha de codigo que o `ViewBag.Compra` está puxando

```
public IList<Compra> Lista()
        {
            string hql = "select c from Compra c;";
            IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql);
            return query.List<Compra>();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o código a seguir para obter o resultado esperado:

```
ViewBag.Compra = Lista()
                        .Select(x => new {Id = x.NomeId, NomeProduto = x.NomeProduto})
                        .Distinct();
```

Comment: Na parte do `NomeId` seria oque? Pois não tem essa variavel no codigo

Comment: NomeId mesmo. Pelo que entendi da estrutura da tabela é que o NomeId é a chave primária do NomeProduto, certo?

Comment: NomeId é o nome de usuario que puxa de outra tabela, irei tenta coloca Id no lugar, ela é a chave primaria

Comment: Teoricamente, você precisa atribuir um Id para o nome do Produto. Ele existe?

Comment: Não, então provavelmente cada produto terá que ter seu Id em especifico, correto?

Comment: Exato, ao invés de incluir o NomeProduto, você inclui o IdProduto. Logo, você terá uma tabela com produtos que poderá ser utilizada de forma mais elegante no DropDownList (Sem a necessidade de Distinct).

Comment: Entendo, o problema que se eu fizer isso, essa tabela aonde está os nomes de produto e seus valores, é requisitados para outras tabelas pegando seus produtos e valores.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69227/discussion-between-jean-gustavo-prates-and-guilherme-padovam).

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode resolver isso apenas na query?

```
select 
 Id, 
 NomeProduto 
from Compra c 
group by Id, NomeProduto
order by NomeProduto
```

Obs.: Talvez precise ajustar o campo do seu Id...